# "Unknown Parent" error on rebundle in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I accidentally stripped the wrong changesets; however, I saved backups, but when I try to unbundle them using `hg unbundle .hg/strip-backup/faa0a1895b97-backup.hg`, I get the following error:

```
adding changesets
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: 00changelog.i@561fe01204b5: unknown parent!
```

What can I do to correct this?

Here's the entire output from `hg verify`:

```
checking changesets
checking manifests                                                              
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests                                 
checking files
```

Comment: This is not the complete output of the "hg verify" the last line should be sth. like: "1132 files, 1121 changesets, 7309 total revisions" if everything is OK.

Comment: @YunusNedimMehel, I'd love to verify that for you, however, this question was written ~9 months ago, and I've long since nuked this repo.

Comment: It's OK, I am getting no warnings form verify, but unknown parent error persists; so it's not the only reason.

Answer (score 0):

If unbundle is telling you that it can't apply the bundle then the parent of that "first" changeset it that bundle, the bundles base, doesn't exist in your repo.  Since repos never lose changesets using normal mercurial commands (strip isn't normal) then it seem you used strip or some other history-altering-not-normal-usage command to alter or remove that changeset.

Try going through all the `.hg/strip-backup/` files and applying them one by one.  Maybe one of them does apply and contains the parent the the strip backup you're trying to apply requires.

Tl;Dr: no normal mercurial command ever deletes anything, and the non-normal ones that do create backups.  Unless you deleted the file out of band the data is there somewhere.

Comment: I did try going through all of the .hg/strip-backup/ files. Unfortunately, none of them applied. :(